# lower_bound and upper bound showing an unexpected behaviour in c++

Tags: c++, stl

I have 2 vectors each containing certain elements

```
   for(int i=0;i<vec1.size();i++){
    int low = lower_bound(vec2.begin(),vec2.end(),vec1[i])-vec2.begin();
    int up = upper_bound(vec2.begin(),vec2.end(),vec1[i])-vec2.begin();
    }

   for(int i=0;i<vec1.size();i++){
    int low = lower_bound(vec1.begin(),vec1.end(),vec2[i])-vec1.begin();
    int up = upper_bound(vec1.begin(),vec1.end(),vec2[i])-vec1.begin();
    }
```

Here is the entire code snippet:

```
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
          for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
            vec1.push_back((arr[i]*arr[j])+arr[k]);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
         for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
         {
           if(arr[k]==0)
           continue;
           else
           vec2.push_back((arr[i]+arr[j])*arr[k]);
          }
sort(vec1.begin(),vec1.end());
sort(vec2.begin(),vec2.end());
int res=0;
    for(int i=0;i<vec1.size();i++)
    {
        int low = lower_bound(vec2.begin(),vec2.end(),vec1[i])-vec2.begin();
        int up = upper_bound(vec2.begin(),vec2.end(),vec1[i])-vec2.begin();
        res+=(up-low);
    }


for(int i=0;i<vec1.size();i++)
        {
            int low = lower_bound(vec2.begin(),vec2.end(),vec1[i])-vec2.begin();
            int up = upper_bound(vec2.begin(),vec2.end(),vec1[i])-vec2.begin();
            res+=(up-low);
        }
```

Now essentially what I am trying to do is find the total number of occurrences of an element in vec1 and vec2.The problem that I am facing is that even though both the codes essentially implement the same logic are giving different values for res.
This should not happen as the logic is same for both of them.
The vectors used are of same size.
Is this somehow an unexpected behaviour of lower bound and upper bound that I am unaware of?

Comment: Are the vectors sorted? `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` only work on sorted sequences.

Comment: Yes.They are sorted

Comment: OK, great. You say that they're giving different output but there's no output shown. Can you give a *complete* code sample?

Comment: No, that's not the real code sample. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your complete code?
I didn't understand what you want in your code?

```
int res=0;
for(int i=0;i<vec1.size();i++)
{
    int low = lower_bound(vec2.begin(),vec2.end(),vec1[i])-vec2.begin();
    int up = upper_bound(vec2.begin(),vec2.end(),vec1[i])-vec2.begin();
    res+=(up-low);
}
for(int i=0;i<vec1.size();i++)
        {
            int low = lower_bound(vec2.begin(),vec2.end(),vec1[i])-vec2.begin();
            int up = upper_bound(vec2.begin(),vec2.end(),vec1[i])-vec2.begin();
            res+=(up-low);
        }
```

If you want to count the number of occurrence of a value in both you should use 2 variables like res1 and res2.

I think you want to do this:

> Ex : if arr = [1,2] then both vec1 and vec2 contains [2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6]
>   after sorting. And you want to find an occurrence of 2,3,4,5 and 6 in
>   both vectors. Am I right?

If yes then you first need to find unique value in your vector.Becuase right now you are searching for value 3 three times in your loop.

Once you convert this both vector into set. Use following code.

```
int res=0;
for(int i=0;i<vec1.size();i++)
{
    int low = lower_bound(vec2.begin(),vec2.end(),vec1[i])-vec2.begin();
    int up = upper_bound(vec2.begin(),vec2.end(),vec1[i])-vec2.begin();
    res+=(up-low);
}

int res2=0;
    for(int i=0;i<vec2.size();i++)
            {
                int low = lower_bound(vec1.begin(),vec1.end(),vec2[i])-vec1.begin();
                int up = upper_bound(vec1.begin(),vec1.end(),vec2[i])-vec1.begin();
                res2+=(up-low);
            }
// Compare res and res2 here.
```

Another thing you missed is that in both loops you are looking in vector1.In the first loop, you should values of set1 in vector2 and in second loop values of set2 in vector1.

Hope this is what you wanted. If not please ask in the comment. I will modify my answer.